# Additional Cost Fee Adding Twice when order placed in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to add a custom add on cost to woocommerce product single page which can be set from product editor and is shown in product single page. And this cost should show in cart page and checkout page and so as in order details in wordpress dashboard. I am able to do it, and working fine. Only problem is that the additional cost is being added twice when order is completed and is shown in order complete page and also in order details in wordpress dashboard. To make it more understandable suppose product cost is 20 and additional cost is set 10. So when someone adding a product to cart then it shows 30 in cart and in cart details page as well and so as in checkout it shows 30. But once you place the order, then it shows as 40 in woocommerce order confirmation page and so as in order meta data. So what is happening is its already adding the additional cost at first when I am adding it to cart and finally adding again when order is placed. So confusing. My code is below. Not sure whats wrong with this

```
<?php

// Add custom addon cost field to product general options
function custom_addon_field()
{
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'          => '_addon_cost',
            'label'       => __('Addon Cost', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder' => __('Enter addon cost', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __('Enter the additional cost for this addon.', 'woocommerce'),
            'type'        => 'number',
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step' => 'any',
                'min'  => '0'
            ),
        )
    );
}

add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'custom_addon_field');

// Save custom addon cost field value
function save_custom_addon_field($post_id)
{
    $addon_cost = isset($_POST['_addon_cost']) ? wc_clean($_POST['_addon_cost']) : '';
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_addon_cost', $addon_cost);
}

add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_addon_field');

// Display custom addon cost on product single page
function display_custom_addon_cost_on_single_product()
{
    global $product;

    $addon_cost = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_addon_cost', true);

    if ($addon_cost) {
        echo '<p class="addon-cost">' . __('Addon Cost:', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . wc_price($addon_cost) . '</p>';
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_custom_addon_cost_on_single_product', 11);


// Add custom addon cost to cart
function add_custom_addon_cost_to_cart($cart_item_data, $product_id)
{
    $addon_cost = get_post_meta($product_id, '_addon_cost', true);

    if ($addon_cost) {
        $cart_item_data['addon_cost'] = $addon_cost;
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_addon_cost_to_cart', 10, 2);



// Calculate custom addon cost in cart totals
function calculate_custom_addon_cost_in_totals($cart)
{
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        if (isset($cart_item['addon_cost'])) {
            $addon_cost = floatval($cart_item['addon_cost']);

            // Set the new price including the addon cost
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['data']->get_price() + $addon_cost);
        }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_custom_addon_cost_in_totals');



// Display custom addon cost in cart and checkout page
function display_custom_addon_cost_in_cart_and_checkout($item_data, $cart_item)
{
    if (isset($cart_item['addon_cost'])) {
        $addon_cost = $cart_item['addon_cost'];
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'     => __('Addon Cost', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'   => wc_price($addon_cost),
            'display' => '',
        );
    }

    return $item_data;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_addon_cost_in_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2);


// Save custom addon cost to order meta
function save_custom_addon_cost_to_order_meta($item_id, $values)
{
    if (isset($values['addon_cost'])) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, __('Addon Cost', 'woocommerce'), $values['addon_cost']);
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'save_custom_addon_cost_to_order_meta', 10, 2);
```

I am trying to add a custom fee to woocommerce product single page and this cost should be shown in cart and checkout page and in order details page. But the problem is that is adding as twice. Thats the problem